# Top Border of Top Cell in UITableView Grouped Cells is Thick & Fuzzy

Tags: iphone, uitableview, image-processing, cell

I am using a UITableView with grouped rows. In each group / section of rows, the top cell has a thicker-than-normal top border and the top rounded corners appear fuzzy. I am not doing anything out of the ordinary with this table.

I have looked at other apps and I do not see the same thing happening.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't just that you're using the `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle?

Try setting you're UITableView's separatorStyle property to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`. (Or just select "Single Line" for the "Seperator" option within the Table View attibutes in Interface Builder if that's how you're creating the UITableView.)

Comment: @Chris - Sometimes it's the easy ones that are the hardest to spot. :-)